# Returns the MySQL inserted object in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database storing users, with their attributes : pseudo, password...

When a user is connecting to my web application, I go to the database and I search the user. With `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User')`, I have directly the result in a PHP object, as an instance of the `User` class. I store it in `$_SESSION['user']`.

When a user is subscribing to my web application, I insert him in the database. I would like to have the user in `$_SESSION['user']`. So I would like to have access to the inserted field as a PHP object, without searching again this user. Is my question clear, and do you know how to do please ?

Comment: `the code::` we need to see it

Comment: Is my question not clear ?

Comment: It is more helpful to see the code

Comment: In fact, I ask this question in order to know the code I need.

Comment: I read the question again, and it is not clear. It could be the reason, why no-one is yet replying. Can you clear it a bit?

Comment: I put something in my database. I want to have the result as a PHP object.

Comment: So... `SELECT` it into an object? Actually, how are you creating the data to be inserted? Are you using an ORM?

Comment: The question was precisely to not use SELECT in order to not re-requesting the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution for you would be too add make a `SELECT` request just after your insert (with the proper PDO flags to load an `User` object.